# Ideals on $\mathbb N$ and large sets that have small intersection

Tags: set-theory, boolean-algebras, infinite-combinatorics, ultrafilters

Let $\mathcal I$ be a (non-principal) ideal of subsets of $\mathbb N$. Suppose that every family $\mathcal{A} \subset \wp(\mathbb N)\setminus \mathcal I$ with the following property is countable:
$$A,B\in \mathcal A, A\neq B \Rightarrow A\cap B \in \mathcal I. $$

Let us observe that maximal ideals have this property as only the empty family or the singletons meet this requirement.

> Are there further examples of ideals with this property?

(As observed by Leonetti every such ideal must be non-meagre when regarded as a subset of the Cantor set.)

Comment: "only the empty family": you mean "only the empty family or singletons". By the way, what you call "family" is usually called a "subset". Of course, every set can be thought of as a family $(a)_{a\in A}$...

Comment: You have all ideals $I$ such that $P(N)/I$ is countable (but this forces $P(N)/I$ finite).

Comment: By the way this is purely ring-theoretic: in a ring $R$ (say associative unital commutative), you considers ideals $I$ and subsets $\mathcal{A}\subset R\smallsetminus I$ such that for all $a\neq b\in\mathcal{A}$ we have $ab\in I$, and require that all such subsets are countable. In a Boolean algebra $a,b\notin I,a-b\in I$ implies $ab\notin I$, so this forces $\mathcal{A}$ to embed into $A/I$. Beyond the Boolean case, this applies when $A/I$ is reduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The denumerable atomless Boolean algebra $A$ can be isomorphically embedded in $\wp(\omega)/\mathsf{fin}$. The identity on $A$ can be extended to a homomorphism from $\wp(\omega)/\mathsf{fin}$ into the completion of $A$. This gives a homomorphic image of $\wp(\omega)/\mathsf{fin}$, hence also of $\wp(\omega)$ itself, in which every disjoint subset is countable. So the kernel of the homomorphism is another ideal of the type indicated.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure the following example is different from the ones already given, but the description is different, and so I hope some readers might find it useful.  Fix a countable family $\mathcal F$ of non-principal ultrafilters on $\mathbb N$, and let $I$ be the ideal of sets that are in none of the ultrafilters in $\mathcal F$. Then $I$ is not maximal, because if $X\subseteq\mathbb N$ is in some but not all of the ultrafilters in $\mathcal F$ then neither $X$ nor its complement is in $I$. (Almost as easily, $I$ is not the intersection of finitely many maximal ideals.)

To prove that $I$ has the countability property in the question, consider any uncountable family $\mathcal A$ of sets not in $I$, Then each set in $\mathcal A$ is in at least one of the ultrafilters in $\mathcal F$. But $\mathcal F$ is countable and $\mathcal A$ is not, so there must be two (in fact uncountably many) sets $A,B\in\mathcal A$ belonging to the same ultrafilter $U\in\mathcal F$. Then $A\cap B$ is in $U$ and therefore not in $I$.

Answer (score 3):

In topological language: for any closed subset, $F$, of $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ the family $I_F=\{A:A^*\cap F=\emptyset\}$ is an ideal.
Your property translates into: the closed set $F$ is a ccc space.

The example by Monk can be made in this way too: take a map $s$ from $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ onto the Cantor set $C$ and take $F$ such that $s:F\to C$ is irreducible and onto, then $F$ is sparable and hence ccc.

The example by Blass corresponds to the closure of a countable set in $\beta\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$, again a separable subspace.

In general: take any compact ccc space, $X$, of weight at most $\mathfrak{c}$ and embed it into the Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\mathfrak{c}$. There is a continuous map $\sigma$ from $\beta\mathbb{N}$ onto that cube. Now take $F$ such that $\sigma:F\to X$ is irreducible and onto; then $F$ is ccc. For a non-separable example let $X$ be the Stone space of the measure algebra.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can use forcing to cook up many examples: Let $P=Add(\omega, 1)$. This is the forcing that adds a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Let $\dot
{U}$ be a $P$-name of a non-principal ultrafilter. We can choose such a name with the property that for some infinite co-infinite $X\subset \omega$, $\not\Vdash_P \check{X}\in \dot{U}$ nor $\not\Vdash_P \check{X^c}\in \dot{U}$.

Define $I=\{X\subset \omega: \Vdash_P X\not\in \dot{U}\}$. This ideal is clearly not principal and is not maximal either (neither $X$ nor $X^c$ is in). Given any $\{A_i\in P(\omega)-I: i<\omega_1\}$, we find $p_i\in P$ such that $p_i\Vdash_P A_i\in \dot{U}$. But $P$ is countable so there exists $i\neq j$ such that $p_i=p_j\Vdash A_i, A_j\in \dot{U}$ hence $p_i=p_j\Vdash_P A_i\cap A_j\in \dot{U}$, which means $A_i\cap A_j\not\in I$. Any forcing with countable chain condition works here.

Answer (score 1):

Another class of examples comes from the ideal of $m$-measure zero sets where $m$ is a finitely additive atomless probability measure on the power set of integers. Such measures can be constructed using Hahn-Banach theorem, ultralimits etc. For example, if $U$ is a non principal ultrafilter on the set of integers, then the $U$-density function $m(A) = \lim_{n \in U} |A \cap [0, n]|/n$ defines such a measure.